# Is there a way to filter Activity Monitor by unresponsive applications?

Tags: macos, performance, activity-monitor

It can sometimes be a slight nuisance to scroll through the whole list in *Activity Monitor* to find unresponsive applications – especially when this happens often and there's a lot of processes going on.

Searching for "red text" as a visual cue is what I usually do. But is there some neat way to filter, or sort, the list to easily find unresponsive applications?

Or, is there some other utility or method, outside of Activity Monitor?

Comment: The force quit menu will show them. Also, if you have a lot of unresponsive applications, something could be wrong with your Mac.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Thanks, your comment answers my question I think :)

Answer (score 1):

When three or more apps are not responsive, it's almost always a symptom of a failure elsewhere. I would select one app and run system diagnostics on it. That gets a full picture of what is wrong and then you can log out and make a list of all the unresponsive apps - they will be the only ones remaining.

When you log in again, start the one app that was hung. You'll quickly know if it has issues or was just waiting for some other resource. In time you can narrow down which apps are "collateral damage" and which are primary failures.